# How combine and output a list properly

Tags: micropython

the following code returns:

abc: [(2022, 5, 14, 13, 35, 57), -7]

I'm trying to get rid of the extra parenthesis after the 57

like this:  abc = (2022, 05, 14, 13, 7, 42, -7)

here is my code:

```
abc = time.localtime()
    
        list(abc)
        
        
        abc = abc[:6]
        abc = [abc] + [-7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 I would do:

```
abc=(*abc, -7)
```

instead of the posted line of code

```
abc = [abc] + [-7]
```

Some short explanations about the `abc=(*abc, -7)`

`*abc` does "unpack" the tuple abc into a list of single values.
Then whe append a value of `-7` and create a new tuple containing all the values.

The original code `[abc]` stores the tuple contained in `abc` in a list with only one element (the tuple from `abc`). After that the value `-7` is appended to the new list, resulting in a list with two elements. The first one beeing the tuple `abc` and the second element beeing the value `-7`.